# Regex-Finding several optional variables

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to find several optional variables in a long text string. It seems to be a simple problem but I expect there is a more simple solution that the one I got.

I need to find the first 10 characters (easy) 12345abcde
and the variables AA1ab12 and AA2abc123 when they exist, in the ADD section:

```
12345abcdeADDAA1ab12
12345abcdeADDxyzAA1ab12
12345abcdeADDxyzAA1ab12xyz
12345abcdeADDAA2abc123
12345abcdeADDAA1ab12xyAA2abc123
12345abcdeADDAA1ab12xAA2abc123y
12345abcdeADDxAA1ab12xAA2abc123y
12345abcdeADDxAA2abc123xAA1ab12y
```

Here is one simplified example and the solution but I'm afraid it takes to many steps to apply and cause performance issues :

- I need to retrieve the first 10 characters and the variables AA1 and AA2 if they exist in the ADD section. https://regex101.com/r/hapeTs/1

I tried to add all the optional variables with a Laziness string between `(^(.{10})(?:(?:ADD).*?(AA1.{4})?.*?(AA2.{6})?.*?)?$)`, and some other options unsuccessfully.

- The real applied problem: getting 8 optional variables from the weather NOAA ISD original format dataset: https://regex101.com/r/E462bd/1

Maybe I miss a regex capability

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if it fixes the problem, but you can omit `{1}` and shorten the alternatives using character classes `(?!A[AJ]1|G[FHM]1|O[CAD]1)` See https://regex101.com/r/66TmiA/1

Comment: Do you process this linewise and if so, how about splitting it in two steps? 1. Extract [`^(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})(.{8})`...](https://regex101.com/r/YMVTfn/1) 2. Match the options: [`(?:A[AJ]|G[FHM]|O[ACD])1.{8}`](https://regex101.com/r/YMVTfn/4) (efficient).

Comment: [Here a demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Dic9b#v8.2.10) how it could be done in PHP (not knowing exact requirements).

Comment: Why do you need to find the first 10 chars and the next 3? Can you assume they're all `12345abcde` and `ADD` per your text sample?

Comment: Thank you for your propositions. 
I need to find for each line exactly n=f+v variables. f are fixed mandatory variables and v are optional variables.
It must be a single regex as it will be the SERDE property of a glue table in AWS. And the result capturing group must have a specific order ( =the order of the columns in Glue) so the variables are properly mapped to the columns (Variable i = capturing group i = column i)
An alternative will be to create one table per optional variable. 

We want to try this AWS Glue table as an easy solution before switching to a more complex ETL.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... The real applied problem: getting 8 optional variables from the weather NOAA ISD original format dataset: ..."*

You can capture the variable data field by asserting the ending value is either,

- the text *"REM"*, for the *"Remarks Data Section"*, page 116.
- the end of the line, `$`
- or, another *data-type*, `[A-Z]{2}\d`

```
(AA1|AJ1|GF1|GH1|GM1|OC1|OA1|OD1)(.+?)(?=REM|$|[A-Z]{2}\d)
```

Here is an example using *Python*.

```py
p = r'(AA1|AJ1|GF1|GH1|GM1|OC1|OA1|OD1)(.+?)(?=REM|$|[A-Z]{2}\d)'
l = [{y.group(1): y.group(2)} for x in s for y in re.finditer(p, x)]
[print(x) for x in l]
```

Output

```
{'GF1': '07991071091004501999031'}
{'OA1': '99901431'}
{'OA1': '99901431'}
{'GF1': '07991021061002501031999'}
{'AJ1': '00039199999999'}
{'GF1': '08991061071004501999999'}
{'OA1': '99901381'}
{'AA1': '06999999'}
{'GF1': '99999081999003601999999'}
```